# Cloud Datafusion Replication Pipeline From SQL Server | Decimal Column issue

Tags: real-time, cdc, google-cloud-data-fusion

SQL Server Realtime Replication pipeline is not working  if table has a column of type `decimal(38, 32)` in the source. It keeps on running but no data is pull.

If I closely look at the Stackdriver logs, I see this error:

> Numeric Field 'XXXXXXXX' has invalid precision '1' and scale '32'. Precision must be at most 38 and scale must be at most 9

The pipeline works if I deselect this column.

Answer (score 1):

- Bigquery is considering decimal(38,32) as a [NUMERIC DECIMAL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#decimal_types) data type that supports precision 38 and scale up to 9.
- I would suggest you to reduce it to the limits that the NUMERIC DECIMAL type admits or use the decimal type BIGNUMERIC DECIMAL which supports precision up to 76 and scale up to 38.